# How to aggregate days by year-month and pivot so that count becomes count_source summed over the month with Python

Tags: python

I am manipulating some data in Python and was wondering if anyone can help.

I have data that looks like this:

```
    count   source  timestamp   tokens
0   1   alt-right-census    2006-03-21  setting
1   1   alt-right-census    2006-03-21  twttr
2   1   stormfront          2006-06-24  head
3   1   stormfront          2006-10-07  five
```

and I need data that looks like this:

```
count_stormfront count_alt-right-census month    token
2                1                      2006-01  setting
```

or like this:

```
           date     token  alt_count  storm_count
4069995 2016-09  zealand        0        0
4069996 2016-09     zero       11        8
4069997 2016-09     zika      295      160
```

How can I aggregate days by year-month and pivot so that count becomes count_source summed over the month?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['source', df['timestamp'].str[:7]]).size().unstack()
```

Result:

```
timestamp         2006-03  2006-06  2006-10
source                                     
alt-right-census      2.0      NaN      NaN
stormfront            NaN      1.0      1.0
```